# Request through Retrofit like open API

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to build POST request like open API what I try to use.But I have error,bad request,code==400.What Im doing wrong and how build right request?
Example of this request in API:

```
curl -X POST
     -H "Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg=="
     -d "username=foo&password=bar" https://api.vid.me/auth/create
```

**my interface class:**

```
public interface VideoApi {

    @GET("/videos/featured")
    Call<Videos> getFeaturedVideo();

    @GET("/videos/new")
    Call<Videos> getNewVideo();

@Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/auth/create")
   Call<SignInResults>insertUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,@Field("username") String username,
                           @Field("password") String password
                           );
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button btnLogin;

    public List<SignInResult> signInResult;
    String username_value,password_value;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_field);
        password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        btnLogin = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Authorize();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void Authorize() {
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);

         username_value = username.getText().toString();
         password_value = password.getText().toString();
String basicauth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s",username_value,password_value).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Call<SignInResults> call = videoApi.insertUser(basicauth,username_value,password_value);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInResults>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignInResults> call, Response<SignInResults> response) {
                SignInResults results = response.body();
                Log.d("Response ==>> ", new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(results));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignInResults> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
}
```

**stack trace:**

```
rawResponse = {Response@830026791184} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
 body = {OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@830025624336} 
 cacheControl = null
 cacheResponse = null
 request = {Request@830024019616} "Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=null}}"
 handshake = {Handshake@830025630784} 
 headers = {Headers@830025578160} "Content-Type: application/json\nDate: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 07:36:04 GMT\nServer: nginx\nSet-Cookie: rid=58132ed5dd9a405f851d7ba3a05238e5; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475092750; path=/; domain=vid.me\nSet-Cookie: srid=kKmWgypTQSSDdiKprKNUdg-DQiaXQ-IrRIa9riWD48kQG4bK4Mzfbu0fk; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475092750; path=/; domain=vid.me\nX-Request-Time: 12\nX-Vidme-Authorization-Okay: false\nX-Vidme-Server-Id: 79dce5c05de58beae1b751040fd8bcd0\nContent-Length: 85\nConnection: keep-alive\nOkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1461638110857\nOkHttp-Received-Millis: 1461638111114\n"
 message = "Bad Request"
 networkResponse = {Response@830025231040} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
 priorResponse = null
 protocol = {Protocol@830023817448} "http/1.1"
 code = 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your request with Postman and the problem is not in Android but it's your API. The error is "The password you entered was not valid" so why the password is invalid ?

See this screen from postman :
[API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIsjf.png)

Have a great day

Comment: its example for username or password,Im trying to enter valid username and password and its bad request.I implement this request in android correct?

Comment: Your API send an error but you sent a username and a password so in the API code check why you are this error ! If you want to simplify API calls use Retrofit : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: yeah,password is incorrect.Thank you for Postman.I didnt know this service,now its be much more easy to check my request